# Form Validation with $.post()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, validation

I am using bassistance.de's Validation jQuery plugin to validate a form `#signup-form`. Instead of submitting the form data directly to the server the usual way, the form data should be submitted AJAX'ly via `$.post()`.

**JS Code**

```
// Validate form
$('.signup-form').validate({
    rules: {
        signupName: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
    }
});


// Submit to Serverside
$('#submit-btn').click(function() {
    $.post('/api/register_user',
        $('#signup-modal .signup-form').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            console.log('posted!');
        }
    );
});
```

**Problem:** If a user entered data that does not pass the jquery validation, the click handler on `#submit-btn` will still allow the form to be submitted! Is there a way to check that there are no validation errors?

Comment: Always make sure to also include a validation in your php file. Validation only in javascript doent stop bots or users without javascript.

Comment: a.... `if ($(".signup-form").validate() ) {...}` ? o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Validate form
$('.signup-form').validate({
    rules: {
    signupName: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
   }
});


// Submit to Serverside
$('#submit-btn').click(function() {
    if ($('.signup-form').valid()) {
        $.post('/api/register_user',
            $('#signup-modal .signup-form').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                console.log('posted!');
            }
        );
     }
});
```

Comment: That doing well :) I missed beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the `submitHandler` option to validate:

```
$('.signup-form').validate({
    rules: {
        signupName: { required: true, minlength: 3 }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
      $.post('/api/register_user',
          $('#signup-modal .signup-form').serialize(),
          success: function() {
              console.log('posted!');
          }
      );
    }
});
```

This will automatically be called once the form is valid.  No need to attach anything new to your submit button or the submit event.